# Razor compilation error '.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, compiler-errors

I'm experiencing the following error on runtime, any ideas how to resolve?

[image: Razor error]

Comment: Use as bellow @if (Model.Items != null){            // your code   }

Comment: Thanks, looks like my changes hadn't been added to the web.config file for Roslyn.